# Large lua numbers are being printed incorrectly

Tags: lua, int64

I have the following test case:

```
Lua 5.3.2  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> foo = 1000000000000000000
> bar = foo + 1
> bar
1000000000000000001
> string.format("%.0f", foo)
1000000000000000000
> string.format("%.0f", bar)
1000000000000000000
```

That last line should be `1000000000000000001`, since that's the value of `bar`, but for some reason it's not. This doesn't only apply to `1000000000000000000`, I've yet to find another number over that one which gives the correct value. Can anyone give an explanation for why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`log2(1000000000000000000)` is between 59 and 60, which means that the binary representation of that number needs 60 bits. `double`-precision floating point numbers have only 53 bits of precision, plus a power-of-two exponent with 11 bits of range. So to store that large of a number as floating point (which is what you requested with the `%f` format specifier), six to seven bits of precision are chopped off the end of the number, and the whole thing is multiplied by a power of two to get it back in range (2<sup>59</sup> in this case, I think). Chopping off those final bits removes the precision that allows `1000000000000000000` and `1000000000000000001` to be distinct from each other.

(This is not a particularly precise description of floating point, apologies if my numbers or descriptions are not exact.)

Answer (score 5):

You're formatting the number as floating-point, not integer. That's what `%.0f` is doing. At some point, floats lose precision. `double`, for example, will lose precision after about 16 decimal digits.

If you want to format an integer as an integer, then you need to format it as an integer, using [standard `printf` rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

```
string.format("%i", bar)
```